# NoClassDefFound when compiling Scala with Java sources

Tags: scala, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project with Scala and Java sources from the command line, using the following two commands:

```
scalac -d . *.scala *.java
javac -d . -cp /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar:. *.java
```

The compile goes fine, however when I try to run the code I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
    at Agent.main(Agent.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

For what it's worth, compiling and running through IntelliJ works fine. Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: How do you run it? Paste whole procedure.
Running away from intelij I recomend using sbt.

Comment: Yeah I would, but unfortunately I've only got scalac available on the machine I need to compile on.

It's run from the command line using `java Agent`

Comment: You also need to pass the classpath arguments to `java`.